# How to convert my jQuery code to AngularJS?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, iframe

Here is my jQuery code so how to convert my jQuery code to AngularJS.

```
$('#iframe').contents().find('#tb2').val('test');
```

I want to fill the value inside the iframe textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Can access the iframe window easily in a directive. Then use dom methods like `querySelector()`

Something like

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('frameDirective', function(){
  return {
    link:function(scope,elem){
       var frameDoc = elem[0].contentWindow.document;
      scope.$on('update-frame', function(e, val){
        frameDoc.querySelector('#tb2').value = val;
      });

    }
  }
})
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/p2SHnyhn230Vu1e9?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview)**</kbd>